# msi - Deployment Setup project for a custom Visual Studio Addin

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, setup-deployment, visual-studio-addins

I have developed a custom Add-In for Visual Studio (2008/2010). At this point I need to 
prepare a *.msi installation package for the add-in, with the

```
Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project.
```

*I need a little guidance about the rules of setting up a deployment package for a custom VS addin.* I have looked through the internet, but couldn't find some details.

For example:

How to set the: 
    DefaultLocation [CommonAppDataFolder][ProductName]

Since the VS has already defined add-in paths where an add-in should be placed

```
Tools-> Options -> Enviroment -> Add-in/Macros Security
```

[image]

how can i get the DefaultLocation from there or how to set it depending on VS version.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set DefaultLocation attribute you can try this:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- click File System Editor icon on top of Solution Explorer
- select Application Folder
- in its Properties pane set the DefaultLocation attribute

For other problems try asking more specific questions.